# i didn't close the one of the end of pipe,is there anything wrong happened?

Tags: c, pipe

i use the pipe to make communication between parent proc and child proc.
the book i read says when in parent proc, i must close pipefd[1], but i didn't do that and nothing other happen,so my question is "if i don't close the pipefd[1], is there anything uncontrolled?"
best regards!

```
int pipefd[2];
if(pipe(pipefd) == -1)
{
    perror("pipe communication error");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
int fd = fork();
if(fd < 0)
{
    perror("fork child process error");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
if(fd != 0)//run in parent proc
{
    int a = -1;
    int i = 1;
    //close(pipefd[1]);                         ## here! ##
    while(i)
    {
        read(pipefd[0], &a, sizeof(a));
        printf("%d\n", a);
        sleep(4);
    }
}
else//run in child proc
{
    int i = 1;
    //close(pipefd[0]);                         ## here! ##
    while(i)
    {
        write(pipefd[1], &i, sizeof(i));
        i++;
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the reader does not close the write end of the pipe, it will not receive the end-of-file when the writer process closes it (because there is still a file descriptor open for the write side).

Answer (score 0):

Well, the recommendation to close the pipe is in order to protect you from yourself: so that your reader process doesn't write accidentally into the pipe, and the writer process doesn't accidentally read some data out. So generally it's a kind of defensive programming technique.

As long as you don't access to the pipe-to-be-closed, nothing bad should happen.

Well, I am not 100% correct here: my statement is true for a simple program like yours, but if you open and forget to close *a lot of* pipes, then your program *leaks* them, and sooner or later (usually after 255 or so open pipes, but YMMV) you wouldn't be able to open a new one. Because the all pipe slots will be used up by the leaked pipes.

This is however not the case for your program.

But nevertheless I would advice to close the pipes. This way you'll get an error if you access the wrong pipe end by mistake.